# Why the inheritance class methods print 0 and null in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, null

I have an Employee class (including fields: empId, name, methods: getEmpId, getName, setEmpId, setName). And I create an inheritance class called HourlyEmployee from Employee. HourlyEmployee class has additional fields: rate, hours, and additional methods: setRate, setHours, monthlyPayment. I create an HourlyEmployee object called he1, when setEmpId and setName are invoked, it prints 0 and null. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
public class Employee {
    // instance variables
    private int empId;
    private String name;

    // constructor
    public Employee(){

}
    public Employee(int empId, String name) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // get methods
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // set methods
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

public static class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private double rate;
    private double hours;

    public HourlyEmployee() {
    }

    public HourlyEmployee (int empId, String name, double rate, double hours) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public double monthlyPayment(){
        double monthlyPayment = rate * hours;
        return monthlyPayment;
    }

    public void employeeInfo(){
        System.out.println("The employee's id is: " + empId);
        System.out.println("The employee's name is: " + name);
        System.out.println("The hourly rate is: " + rate);
        System.out.println("The employee worked " + hours + " for a month");
    }
}


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id;
        String name;
        double rate;
        double hours;
        double salary;
    
        // create an hourly employee object with no-arg constructor
        HourlyEmployee he1 = new HourlyEmployee ();
        // set instance variables
        he1.setEmpId(1);
        he1.setName("Jane");
        he1.setRate(15.0);
        he1.setHours(50.0);

        // display employee info
        he1.employeeInfo();
        // display monthly payment
        System.out.println("Monthly payment, before change, is: " + he1.monthlyPayment());
    
        // change the rate
        he1.setRate(22.0);
        // display monthly payment
        System.out.println("Monthly payment, after change, is: " + he1.monthlyPayment());
```

Comment: By re-declaring fields with same name you are creating *separate variables* (even if they have same name). Don't do that. Instead of declaring name and ID again pass specific values to fields in superclass. In constructor you can achieve it via `super(empId, name);`. Also since those fields in supertype are private to *get* their value use getter methods like `System.out.println("The employee's id is: " + getEmpId());`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's great to learn super().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is:

1. `HourlyEmployee` does not know anything about the fields `empId` and `name` of the superclass `Employee`, as they are private. The fields with the same names in `HourlyEmployee` are actually unrelated to those, they are completely separate.
2. `HourlyEmployee` does not override the setters and the getters for these fields, so they still refer to the fields in the base class `Employee`.
3. The constructor of `HourlyEmployee` does not explicitly invoke a super constructor, so the default constructor is implicitly invoked.

I'd recommend to remove the default constructor from Employee if these fields should always be set explicitly. And `HourlyEmployee` should initialize these fields using the constructor that accepts these parameters:

```
public static class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
    private double rate;
    private double hours;

    public HourlyEmployee (int empId, String name, double rate, double hours) {
        super(empId, name);
        this.rate = rate;
        this.hours = hours;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much so such specific explantation. It works well as expected. I didn't know super() before, good to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not declare this two fiels in HourlyEmployee class.

```
private int empId;
private String name;
```

When you call `setEmpId` and `setName`, you are calling Employee's method which set `empId` and `name` in `Employee`. But when you call `employeeInfo`, you are displaying `empId` and `name` in HourlyEmployee which is two totally different field from Employee's `empid` and `name`. And the 0 and null is the default value if `int` and `String`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend a class, the you shouldn't re-declare fields

You have in `Employee`

```
private int empId;
private String name;
```

Do not re-declare in `HourlyEmployee`

Also, why are this class `static` ?